# Ошибка при повторном открытии модального окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. При повторном открытии модального окна возникает ошибка

> Cannot set Visibility or call Show,
> ShowDialog, or
> WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after
> a Window has closed.

Как её устранить?

```
Window w = new Window();

w.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) 
{ 
   e.Cancel = true; 
   this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; 
}
```